# Using arrays as array values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Can I use arrays as array values? I have lots of rows in a HTML table: only first column and other columns data array is changing.

I've tried following code but it seems not working.

```
$period['areas']['AREA I'] = "Area 1";
$period['areas']['AREA II'] = "Area 2";
// and so on...

$customerCountTotal = array();
$customerCountTotal[1]['AREA I'] = 700;
$customerCountTotal[1]['AREA II'] = 500;
$customerCountActive[1]['AREA I'] = 300;
// and so on...

for ($counter = 1; $counter <= 7; $counter++) {

    $rowArray = array("Customers" => $customerCountTotal, "&ndash; active customers" => $customerCountActive /* etc. */);

    foreach ($rowArray as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
        echo "<td style='text-align: right;'>" . $key . "</th>";

        if(isset($period['areas'])) {
            foreach ($period['areas'] as $key2 => $value2) {
                echo "<td style='text-align: right;'>".$value[$counter][$key2]."</td>";
            }
        }

        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

There might be a better way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uh, what? Could you clarify? I don't get the "Using arrays as array values"

Comment: hi, can you write a example of table that you need!

Comment: <td style='text-align: right;'>" . $key . "</th>     open td and close th

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, any value or type can be stored in an array, including other arrays.

Arrays that are simply values stored against an index simply have *one dimension* to them, but what we're talking about is creating a nested array, also known as a *multidimensional* array - an array with other arrays as values.

For reference, the following array:

```
$array = array(
    array("Top left", "Top centre", "Top right"),
    array("Left", "Middle", "Right"),
    array("Bottom left", "Bottom centre", "Bottom right"),
);
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
$array = array();
$array []= array("Top left", "Top centre", "Top right"),
$array []= array("Left", "Middle", "Right"),
$array []= array("Bottom left", "Bottom centre", "Bottom right"),
```

Two great resources for learning more are:

1. [Using Multidimensional Arrays](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-php-5/0596005601/ch04s05.html)
2. [The PHP manual on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) has a great section about multidimensional arrays.

Comment: They're not multi-dimensional - they are nested. It is possible to *represent* multi-dimensional arrays as nested arrays, but not vice versa. The former (by definition) is indexed by ordinal numbers only, further an array element exists for any possible set of coordinates within the range limits of each dimension in a multi-dimensional array (not true for nested arrays). I'm quite aware that there is reference to multi-dimesnional arrays in the PHP manual; its wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'd say that you are putting multidimensionnal arrays as array members, which is possible.